# Weird viewport when X,Y,Z coordinates are really high

Tags: 3d-view

I have a mesh that is geo-referenced using some global reference where my X, Y and Z coordinates of the center are really high.

When I Align my view around the 3D cursor (same as the mesh center), I have a weird viewport where several faces are transparent.

When I move the whole model into X=0, Y=0 and Z=0 for example, the problem disappears (picture 2)

I would like to keep working with the original coordinates though. Any idea why I have this effect ?

Thanks for your help how to solve this issue,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reminds me of the game Outer Wilds, due to floating point precision everything works better when the player is at 0,0,0 so instead of moving the player character they apply the opposite force to every other entity in the game.  It's all about your frame of reference.

Comment: what should I do then ? make a delta transformation, get everything move to 0,0,0, do what I have to do and make the same delta transformation again ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with python but scripting might provide a solution.  If you parent an empty at the current origin, you should be able to move your mesh around, apply the location, and the empty should have the inverse transform. (If I'm thinking about this correctly :p)

Comment: "*I would like to keep working with the original coordinates*" Why, is it for the convenience of entering familiar coordinates? I'd advise moving everything as close to world zero as possible a known easy to work distance like say 500000,400000, so you don't have to do a lot of mental calculations. Coordinates will still be recognizable minus a few thousands